# Segmentation fault randomly using fgets(), only happening on linux server not my own distro

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, fgets

Hey guys I am working on a program that is supposed to mimic some basic functions of tr. I have a bunch of tests that sometimes will pass and other times will segfault (Return 139). Ive been trying to figure this out for a while now and am honestly out of ideas.

```
char echo_array[256];
while ((fgets(echo_array, 255, stdin)) != NULL)
{
  for (int i = 0; echo_array[i] != EOF; i++)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < strlen(argv[1]); j++){

      if (echo_array[i] == argv[1][j])
      {
        echo_array[i] = argv[2][j];
      }
    }
  }
  printf("%s", echo_array); 
}
return 0;
```

} 
}

Comment: [fgets returns](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) read string or NULL if didn't read anything and hit EOF, it doesn't return EOF. In firs `for(...)` you're trying compare elements of read string (characters) with EOF which is not going to work.

Comment: Thank you.. Not sure how I didn't realize this earlier. I guess since it was working sometimes I thought there was no issue.. Fixed it by changing the outer for loop to just iterate through the whole array instead of checking for EOF which never shows up. or as Nate said could just check for the null termination character.. Thanks guys

Comment: stop calling `strlen` inside a for loop. Store the length in a variable before entering the loop

Comment: Not sure what the difference would be. I guess every time it iterates through the for loop it will redo the calculation so it is therefore inefficient? Is that what you are getting at? Not sure if the compiler will pick that up though and store it in a register.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comparison `echo_array[i] != EOF` should be `echo_array[i] != '\0'`.  Strings in C are terminated with a zero character, not with EOF.

Comment: Thanks man, yea Im not sure why I forgot fundamental c knowledge. Should have assumed the segfault was from trying to access an invalid index of the array. Still a little confusing on why it wasn't happening on my Ubuntu distro but was on a CentOS server. Im guessing this could be because of how the stdin is carried out. It would exit with error only around 10% of the time on Ubuntu whereas CentOS it would happen nearly every time running the exact same test scripts.

Comment: It's [probably] not worth speculating as to why it [might have] worked on centos, because checking for `EOF` [vs. 0] is UB, and after that, all bets are off. UB [in this context], means it _might_ work [due to some serendity], might segfault, or just produce unexpected/wrong results. From what you've said, after the end of `echo_array`, centos had 0xFF somewhere immediately after and that stopped the loop, but, under ubuntu, it didn't. In both cases, you were going beyond bounds, and it's just luck that it didn't scribble on critical data [like a function return address] and segfault.